# Integral Representation of an Inverse function

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

I'm interested in determining a closed form expression of $f^{-1}(x)$ where
$$
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1-4x} \cot \left[ \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1-4x} \,\right] ~. 
$$
Note that this function is one-to-one for $x>-\frac{3}{4}$. In this range, the function can be inverted. I'm hoping to find an integral representation of the inverse of the form

$f^{-1}(x) = \int_0^1 g(x,t) dt$

for some function $g(x,t)$. I honestly don't even know where to start or if it is even possible (not a HW question).

Any ideas?

Comment: Once you have one representation for $f^{-1}(x)$, one example of such an integral is $\int_0^1f^{-1}(x)dt$. I'm pretty sure that inverse doesn't exist in terms of elementary functions though. Also note that you will need a restricted domain for the inverse, since $x\cot x$ is not injective.

Comment: Yes. I should have specified what domain I'm interested in. I'll edit and put in some details.

Comment: We have $\displaystyle x\cot x=1-2\sum_1^\infty\zeta(2n)(\frac{x}{\pi})^{2n}$ and is not an elementary function.

Comment: @user3798897 - I made some changes to the question.

Comment: @MyGlasses - I am not restricting myself to elementary functions...

Answer (score 1):

I think this question very hard to solve, well, let
$$g(x)=x\cot x$$
and
$$h(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}$$
so
$$
f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}\cot\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}\,\right]
=goh(x)
$$
What's $f^{-1}=h^{-1}o g^{-1}$. we know $\displaystyle h^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{4}-\Big(\frac{x}{\pi}\Big)^2$ for $\displaystyle x<\frac14$, so the problem is finding inverse of $g^{-1}$.

$$\cdots$$